# Magnetic force and work done

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, applied-physics

If magnetic force do no work at all then how do magnets attract or repel each other?

Comment: magnetic fields have energies associated and the repulsion us just a consequence of modifying energy so as to keep total energy constant

Comment: The force between two magnets $\neq$ the Lorentz force. It's only the Lorentz magnetic force which can do no work.